# Looking for class of functions $f_n$ with $n$ variables $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $f_n=k_n a^{n−1}$ if $x_i=a\;\forall i$

Tags: functions

Is there a class of functions that fulfills or partly fulfills following conditions?

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}$ there is a function $f_n$ with following properties:

1. $f_n$ is a function of $n$ variables, i.e. $f_n=f_n(x_1,...,x_n)$ with $x_i\ge0 \;\forall i$
2. if $x_i=a \;\forall i\;$ then $f_n=k_n a^{n-1}$ with $k_n>0$
3. $f_n\ge0$
4. $f_n=0$ iff $x_i=0 \;\forall i$

It is not known that 1-4 are sufficient conditions to define a unique function class but it would be good to know at least one class that fulfills all conditions.

### What is known?

Following function scheme fulfills conditions 1,2 but not conditions 3,4 and might be a starting point:

$$f_n=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}$$
As an expample $n=4$ is used:

condition 1 fulfilled:
$$f_4=\frac{x_1x_2x_3x_4}{\frac{1}{4}\left(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\right)}$$

condition 2 fulfilled:
$$f_4=\frac{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a}{\frac{1}{4}\left(a+a+a+a\right)}=a^3 \;\;\;\text{with}\;\;\; k_4=1$$

condition 3 only fulfilled if $\neg(x_i=0\; \forall i)$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ge0 \land \prod_{i=1}^n x_i\ge0 \to f_4\ge0$$

condition 4 not fulfilled:
$$f_4=\frac{0\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1}{\frac{1}{4}\left(0+1+1+1\right)}=0 \nleftrightarrow x_i=0\; \forall i$$

Comment: What about f_n= x_2 x_3 .... x_n?

Comment: Or f_n = (x_1 x_2 ... x_n )^((n-1)/n) ?

Comment: These functions do not fulfill condition 4.

Comment: (x_1 + x_2 ... +x_n)^(n-1)?

Comment: $f_n(x)=  x_1^{n-1}\,k_n\frac{\|x\|}{\|a\|}$

Comment: Or simply take any function $g \colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ which is $0$ only at $0$ (e.g. $g(x)=\tanh(x)$) and define $f_n(x)=  x_1^{n-1}\,k_n\frac{g(\|x\|)}{g(\|a\|)}$. Also, you can combine this with @RainerGlüge suggestion and take for instance $f_n(x)=  (\frac{x_1^p+x_2^p+x_8^p}{3})^{\frac{n-1}{p}}\,k_n\frac{g(\|x\|)}{g(\|a\|)}$ with $p>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting the comment from user Rainer Glüge following function class fulfills all conditions.
$$f_n=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{n-1}$$

It can easily be shown that the 4 conditions are fulfilled and it is exemplary shown for $n=4$.

condition 1 fulfilled:
$$f_n=(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^3$$

condition 2 fulfilled:
$$f_n=(a+a+a+a)^3=k_4a^3\;\;\;\text{with}\;\;\;k_4=64$$

condition 3 fulfilled:

follows from definition of  $x_i\ge0\;\forall i$

condition 4 fulfilled:

follows from definition of  $x_i\ge0\;\forall i$, 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0 \leftrightarrow x_i=0\;\forall i$$
$$0^3=0 $$

---

There might be other more complicated expressions that also fulfill all conditions.